# Arrayformula (google sheets) in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Is there a way to use Arrayformula function as used in google sheets in Excel?

For example:

```
 A     B
```

1|  23
2|  45
3|  56

If I'll write in b1 =Arrayformula(A1:A3*2)

I'll get

```
 A     B
```

1|  23 | 46
2|  45 | 90
3|  56 | 112

How can I get same result on Excel 2007 using 1 formula (without dragging/ copying/ double clicking)

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the range were you want the answers.

In your example select range `"B1:B3"`

type `=A1:A3*2`

Now the trick is press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` instead of `Enter`.

> PS: Ctrl + Shift + Enter makes the formula as an arrayformula

Comment: Great, it works for that case,

But mostly I need to you it on a dynamic range of cells, In google sheets I just enter " Arrayformula(A2:A*2)

But in excel it looks like it's not working, is there a solution for that as well ?

Comment: Sorry, In Excel the range does'nt get adjusted automatically. Other Workaround assuming you will use 1000 rows only. Select till 1000 and then `=IF(A1:A1000*2=0,"",A1:A1000*2)` Ctrl Shift Enter. Beware this can increase file size and slow down your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just highlight the range B1:B3 and enter your formula

```
=A1:A3*2
```

followed by  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that the formula will be 'locked in' to B1:B3 and you won't be able to change an individual cell in the range without changing the other cells.

Comment: Great, it works for that case, But mostly I need to you it on a dynamic range of cells, In google sheets I just enter " Arrayformula(A2:A*2) But in excel it looks like it's not working, is there a solution for that as well ?

Comment: Yes, agree with @vasim. Other suggestion is just to use =IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1*2) (not an array formula) and pull down to as many rows as you think you might use.

Answer (score 0):

Not an array formula, but could be a good solution- put your data into a table on excel by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl` + `L` (excel will size the table to cover the cells with data).

Then enter your formula in the column just to the right, the table will expand to include it and the formula will be repeated for every row in the table.

If you add an extra row the formula will be automatically updated too.

(I would note that you need excel 2006+ to have this feature, it's one of my favourites)